# Overlapping of itemTpl contents on x-list-item

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have been using **Sencha Touch 2.0**, I tried to create a list item including pics and the other data, but the records are overlapping on other item rows. you can view the image below:

[image]

The code of the page is below:

```
Ext.define('SBR.view.Comments', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    xtype : 'commentspage',
    config : {
        title : 'Comments',
        iconCls : 'star',
        variableHeights: true,
        store : 'Comments',
        itemTpl : '<div class="colmask ">'
                + '<div class="colmid">'
                + '<div class="colleft">'
                + '<div class="col1">'
                + '<div>'
                + '<img src={imageUrl} alt={firstName} width="50" height="70">'
                + '</div>' // Image of Student
                + '<div>'
                + '<img src={bookImageUrl} alt={firstName} width="50" height="70">'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>'// Image of Book
                + '</div>' // left_leftcolumn
                + '<div class="col2">{firstName}&nbsp;{lastName}</div>'
                + '</div>' // left column
                + '<div id="col3"></div>' + '</div>' // colmask
        /*onItemDisclosure : function(item) {
            console.log('Disclose more info on' + " " + item.data.subject);
        }*/
    }
});
```

Any help from anyone?

Comment: Try setting styleHtmlContent to true using setStyleHtmlContent() function.

Comment: In CSS give some height to `.colmask`

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent work around. I'm not that good at divs myself, and often have the same problems that you're facing. My workaround is that I use tables instead. So in your case, that would be

```
itemTpl : ''+
    '<table>'+
    '    <tr class="myCSSClass">'+
    '        <td><img src={imageUrl} alt={firstName} width="50" height="70"></td>'+
    '        <td><img src={bookImageUrl} alt={firstName} width="50" height="70"></td>'+
    '    </tr> '+
    '. . . . .   '+ 
    '</table>',
```

Btw this is just an example, since I can't really tell what you're trying to achieve without looking at your css

Answer (score 0):

Set height of list itemTpl.. Or apply CSS(background etc through  tag)... This will solve your proble